# Query to only retrieve records that are not duplicated

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, distinct

This is my table structure for product

> product_id   product_name
>   ---------------------------------
>   100            Mouse
>   101            Keyboard
>   101            Pendrive   
>   102            Motherboard
>   102            Card Reader
>   103            Adapter

I want the query which will give me following output by eliminating the duplicate record 
OUTPUT
------------------
100
103

I have tried this query

```
SELECT count(product_id)
FROM product 
GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: what query did you write/use ?

Comment: You can do that with the `HAVING count` clause to a `GROUP BY` (there are other ways depending on what exactly you want to do).

Comment: Title edited as it was entirely misleading...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM product 
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(product_id) = 1;
```

Comment: Don't forgot to accept anyone answer which works for you so community can trust you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this SQL

`SELECT t1.product_id FROM (SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table  GROUP BY product_id) t1 WHERE t1.cnt = 1`